# How can I pass an object to my class under test in a UnitTest class?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, inject

I want to test a class that has an "ObjectMapper" as an instance variable:

```
public class EventTransformerImpl implements EventTransformer {


 @Inject
 private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private String convertParametersToJson(NotificationConfig config) {
        String parametersAsJson = null;
        try {
            parametersAsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(config.getOrdinaryParameters());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info("There was a problem in writing json:" + config.getParameters(), e);
            parametersAsJson = null;
        }
        return parametersAsJson;
    }
}
```

this class does not have any "setter" or "constructor" for initializing "objectMapper" (it is initialized using "spring"):

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="dateFormat">
        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

when I want to test "EventTransformerImpl" class, objectMapper has null value, how can I pass "objectMapper" to "EventTransformerImpl" in my unit test class.

Comment: Is there a reason not to add a setter to the class you're testing?  Increasing testability increases maintainability.

Comment: @David Wallace I agree fully for the  testability. But a setter allows the mutability. I would rather use a constructor if the mutability of the dependency is not required.

Comment: True.  A constructor is better, at least while there's only one field to set.

Comment: @user2688902, Make a habit of accepting the answer if you get it so that it will encourage the people to answer more questions in future. It also helps others in finding the correct solution quickly.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical example where a mock framework, such as [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/), can help you:

```
public class TestClass {
  @Mock
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @InjectMocks
  private EventTransformer eventTransformer;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUp() {
    eventTransformer = new EventTransformerImpl();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }  
}
```

Here, `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` are parts of the Mockito framework. The magic happens in `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` which will scan `this`, which in this case is `TestClass`, for these annotations. Mockito initializes `objectMapper` as a mock, and injects it into `eventTransformer`. You can then use Mockito to decide how `objectMapper` should behave.

You can read more about Mockito [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Also, `@BeforeMethod` is a TestNG method, analogue with JUnits `@Before`.

---

However, many people prefer [*constructor injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection), as proposed by [*davidxxx*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41822811/1421925). This will make it clearer which dependencies `EventTransformerImpl` has, and forces it to be initialized with the correct dependencies. By doing this, there is no need to "magically" (I guess Mockito uses reflection under the hood) inject the dependencies, simply initialize the class to be tested by calling the constructor.

Your class could look something like this (here using Spring's `@Autowired` annotation):

```
public class EventTransformerImpl implements EventTransformer {

  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Autowired
  public EventTransformerImpl(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
  }

  private String convertParametersToJson(NotificationConfig config) {
    String parametersAsJson = null;
    try {
      parametersAsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(config.getOrdinaryParameters());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.info("There was a problem in writing json:" + config.getParameters(), e);
      parametersAsJson = null;
    }
    return parametersAsJson;
  }
}
```

This will be less error prone, because with `@InjectMocks`, Mockito will silently ignore the injection if it fails, while calling a constructor gives the test class full control of the initialization of the test.

Comment: The solution works and it reduces the written code. What we can consider as a good thing. But personally I don't use it because it  has some important drawbacks. 1) it promotes a non transparent design. When you look the test code you have not a setup method that explicitly show how the dependencies are set  2) it promotes a not natural way to write, to read and to understand a test.  If you practice TDD or you develop by relying on tests as lead, you will never use it 3) it is error prone since if the injection fails, Mockito won't report failure.

Comment: @davidxxx That is exactly why I added the last section to my answer. Use constructor injection, which is supported by Spring. This will "fix" point 1 and 3. Simply remove the `@InjectMocks` annotation and create the object using the constructor. I don't really get what you mean with point 2? Do you think it is a bad thing to mock `objectMapper`?

Comment: No doubt you are aware of the problem and you know the solution but I would give all personal reasons why I don't use this Mockito mechanism. For the point 2, the idea is when you write a test in a plain way or in TDD , you write something that seems natural and straight understandable  in the setup. For example : Something like : `EventTransformer transformerToTest = new EventTransformer(objectMapperMock);` While  `eventTransformer = new EventTransformerImpl();   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is  less natural and understandable.

Comment: @davidxxx Yes, I totally agree with that. I somehow got the feeling you where against the mocking of `objectMapper`. I might extend the constructor injection part of my answer.

Comment: I have not answered sorry but no you are right it is a good thing to mock a dependency in a unit test. Your answer is already good, as you wish :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention...(:

Answer (score 1):

1) A class should be testable naturally : why not adding a constructor in `EventTransformerImpl`  to inject the mapper ?

You could do something like that in the spring configuration :

```
  <bean id="EventTransformer" class="EventTransformerImpl">
      <constructor-arg ref="objectMapper"/>
   </bean>
```

And in the test you could instantiate `EventTransformerImpl` with a `ObjectMapper` mocked dependency in the constructor.

2) The other solution is using reflection to inject the field in the class under test in the test method.

You could use the [`setField()` method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) of`ReflectionTestUtils` class of Spring to set the dependency or if you didn't use Spring you could have writen a simple utility method to do the job :

```
public static final void injectValue(String fieldName, Object fieldValue, Object targetObject) {
    try {
        Field f = targetObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(targetObject, fieldValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Since Spring is used, it might be better to use `ReflectionTestUtils`, instead of writing an own method doing the reflection.

Comment: Totally agree. I didn't remember the class to do it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For injecting Spring dependencies in JUnit tests and other objects they depend on I use

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:testBeans.xml" })
public class TestRunner {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
```

You can provide in-code bean initialization as well

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configuration
```

Read more at https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/

Comment: Although there are plenty of answers on other questions that already give this answer; I still upvoted; as you were the first one to point out that Spring has its means to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

All three answers are good; so I don't need to repeat the details of those, but I think it is worth to "align" on the "complete" picture.

As shown **Spring** has built-in means to do injection for unit tests; and you could just go forward and use that. But of course, that means that you are even more "coupling" your business logic code to the Spring framework.

So, if you ever consider re-using your code in a non-Spring situation, then you will find that not only your production code, but also your unit tests will require major rework in order to be used without Spring.

Thus there is a certain merit in the two other answers that suggest to **change** your production code to enable you to at least fully test your production code without adding a dependency to Spring here.

Comment: I can not change the Spring config or original class... I just want to Edite the test class....Thanks(: